# Bind object in repeat.for to custom element

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a custom element called `contact`, the purpose of this element is that it serves as a chat messenger contact. I have an array in the parent called `contacts`. It looks like this:

```
contacts = [
    {
        firstName: 'First name',
        lastName: 'Surname'
    }
];
```

The parent HTML is called `messages`and what I want to happen is that in a `repeat.for` statement the data from this array gets bound to the custom element. I have already tried this

`<contact repeat.for="contact of contacts"></contact>`

But how do I bind `contact` in the repeat.for to the custom element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have contact.js

```
 import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
 export class Contact {
    @bindable data;
 }
```

in contact.html

```
 <template>
    ${data.firstName}&nbsp;${data.lastName}
 </template>
```

in messages.js

```
 export class Messages {
    contacts = [
     {
      firstName: 'First name',
      lastName: 'Surname'
     }
    ];
 }
```

in messages.html

```
 <template>
   <require from="./contact"></require>
   <contact repeat.for="contact of contacts" data.bind="contact"></contact>
 </template>
```